# Allow https connection

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I am trying to connect to a web server using `https` but I am having `Trust anchor for certification path not found.` I don't have the certificate of the web server but I want my application to allow connection to the server. However, I am only finding solutions about trusting all `https` connection. I only want to trust a certain web server. What approach do I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: You can allow connection to only a certain ip. *Note:* this is probably not very secure.

Comment: @Oleg how can I do that? I am 100% sure I can trust the `IP` of the web server.

Comment: What's the problem? Just connect by using ip instead of host. Somebody would still be able to create a private network and configure a server with that ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you use https without a certificate it is useless. The certificate ensures that the connection is not manipulated by a hacker. So you should get a certificate or use http.